# SQL Insert or Update with respect to particular column

Tags: sql, insert, insert-update

My **Order** table is

```
**O_ID            Emp_ID          Bill**
-------------------------------------------
1                  1                20
2                  1                20
3                  2                10
4                  3                20
5                  2                10
```

i want to insert data in **Bill** table like with respect to EmpID

```
**Bill_ID      Emp_ID   TotalBill**
-------------------------------------------
1                  1                40
2                  2                20
3                  3                20
```

but when new row is added in **Order** table

```
 **O_ID            Emp_ID          Bill**
    -------------------------------------------
    1                  1                20
    2                  1                20
    3                  2                10
    4                  3                20
    5                  2                10
    6                  3                50
```

updated **Bill** table should be like

```
**Bill_ID      Emp_ID   TotalBill**
-------------------------------------------
1                  1                40
2                  2                20
3                  3                70
```

i want Insert OR Update Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to check row exists or not, If exists then update or do insert operation.

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM Bill WHERE Bill_ID = 1 AND EMP_ID= 1 )
BEGIN
INSERT statement
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE statement
END
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the simple view with the following

```
Create view total_bill
as
select emp_id, sum(bill) as bill from Order
group by emp_id
```

Comment: i want to insert record in **Bill** Table